# Updating table from a view, error: table must be contained in source tables, but was not found

Tags: sql, lua, exasolution

I'm trying to update a table from a view in Exaplus (which uses the Lua scripting language) but I keep getting the same error.

A simple update to the schema_1 table works but when I try updating a table with a view from schema_2 I always get the same error no matter how much I simplify the code.

The parameters in both the table and the view are the same datatype (varchar(3)).
I have also confirmed that it is not a permission issue.

This is the code I'm running.

```
UPDATE schema_1.table1
SET table1_parameter = a.view_parameter
FROM schema_2.view_name AS a
WHERE table1_parameter_2 IS NOT NULL
```

The expected result is the table being updated, however upon running this code I get the following error:

```
[42000] UPDATE-target-table must be contained in source tables, but was not found [line 4, column 1]
```

Comment: Where you established relation between table and view?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you rephrase? @mkRabbani

Comment: Post your both table and view structure and mention the Key column between two table. Only then people will able to help you to the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Table1` must be a part of your statement to work. You need to `join` these two tables in other case sql don't know which row from your `view` should align with which row from `table1`.

```
UPDATE a1
SET table1_parameter = a.view_parameter
FROM schema_1.table1 AS a1
JOIN schema_2.view_name AS a
    on a1.keyColumn = a.keyColumn
WHERE table1_parameter_2 IS NOT NULL
```